# How can I define my return type

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
   public IList<Content.Grid> GetContentGrid(string pk)
    {
        // How can I define result to hold the return 
        // data? I tried the following but it does not
        // work:
        var result = new IList<Content.Grid>();

        var data = _contentRepository.GetPk(pk)
             .Select((t, index) => new Content.Grid()
             {
                 PartitionKey = t.PartitionKey
                 ....
             });

        switch (pk.Substring(2, 2))
        {
            case "00":
                return data
                    .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                    .ToList();
                break;
            default:
                return data
                    .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                    .ToList();
                break;

        }
    }
```

The VS2012 is telling me that the break is not needed so what I would like to do is to remove the returns from inside the switch, store the results in a variable and then after the switch is completed have:

```
return result;
```

Can someone tell me how I can declare the variable called result. I tried the following but this gives a syntax error:

```
var result = new IList<Content.Grid>();
```

Comment: If IList is an interface, you can't instansiate them.

Comment: Why don't you keep the returns and delete the breaks? And why do you have a switch where the two branches are completely equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already return the result in your switch:

```
return data
    .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
    .ToList();
```

There's no need to declare a variable before/return it after the switch, because you jump out of the switch with the return-statement. (That's why you don't need the break)

However, you could use the following:

```
IList<Content.Grid> result;
```

...

```
case "00":
            result = data
                .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                .ToList();
            break;
        default:
            result = data
                .OrderBy(item => item.Order)
                .ToList();
            break;
```

...

```
return result;
```

Comment: You've got needless brackets in your variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

IList is an interface. You can't construct instances of interfaces. You must create an instance of a concrete type that implements that interface, such as:

```
var result = new List<Content.Grid>();
```

Comment: This needlessly creates a List that will then be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

`IList` is an interface and it cannot be instantiated. You need to pick specific implementation of `IList` and create object of non-abstract class, like, for example, `List`:

```
var result = new List<Content.Grid>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't instansiate an interface, only implement them.

```
public class SomeList<T> : IList<T>
{

}
```

You need a type parameter to go to the `IList`, so have that in your normal class

```
IList<T> result = New SomeList<T>();
```

That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `var`, and you'll be fine; you don't need a default value as it'll just get overwritten.

```
IList<Content.Grid> result;
```

Comment: -1. var is not the problem here, it's the instantiation of an interface.

Comment: @Tarka No it's not. You don't _need_ to instantiate anything at this point; the variable gets assigned in the `switch`.

Comment: Your answer says "Don't use var, and you'll be fine." If the code was `IList<Content.Grid> result = new IList<Content.Grid>();` it still wouldn't work. You answer suggests the use of `var` is the problem, but it isn't. Also, you don't need brackets in your answer.

Comment: @TarkaDaal Answering the _actual question asked_, rather than the made-up question `How do I instantiate an IList`, the _answer_ is "Create an unassigned variable before the `switch`, assign to it in the `switch`, and then return it". There is no reason to create a dummy `List<...>` that you immediately overwrite. Thank you for the point about the brackets, though.

Comment: The actual question the OP asked is "Can someone tell me how I can declare the variable called result". Your way of writing the code is more elegant, I'm not arguing with you. However, `var` has nothing to do with either your solution or the OP's problem.